# How can I use updated value of date1 in 2nd if block. showing error "date1 cannot be resolved"

Tags: java

public class test {

```
public static void check1 (String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

     if(date.matches("^\\w+.+")) {
        Date date1 = sdf2.parse(date);
    }
    else {
        Date date1 = sdf1.parse(date);
    }
    
    Date current  = new Date(); 
    
    if(date1.compareTo(current)<-1) {
        System.out.println("In Past");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Same or future date");
    }
```

How can I use the updated value of date1 in second if block.

Answer (score 1):

A variable is only visible within the scope it is declared (between it's enclosing { and } ).

Your 2 date1 variables are declared (Date date1) within the scope of the if and the else blocks. Therefore they are not visible outside (they effectively don't exist outside of those scopes).

You need to declare it outside:

```
public static void check1(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");

    Date date1; // <- declare date1 here
    if (date.matches("^\\w+.+")) {
        date1 = sdf2.parse(date);
    } else {
        date1 = sdf1.parse(date);
    }

    Date current = new Date();

    if (date1.compareTo(current) < -1) {
        System.out.println("In Past");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Same or future date");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your variable in a scope, which is ending when you close your bracket, aka it is no longer alive after that. What you could do is you can take it out:

```
public static void check1 (String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
    Date date1;
     if(date.matches("^\\w+.+")) {
        date1 = sdf2.parse(date);
    }
    else {
        date1 = sdf1.parse(date);
    }
    
    Date current  = new Date(); 
    
    if(date1.compareTo(current)<-1) {
        System.out.println("In Past");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Same or future date");
    }
}
```